# Form doesn't see file uploader - php

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm attempting to build my first form/file uploader (I'm a newb fyi).

I am testing on a local server on my mac, both the form, file handler, and the uploads folder are in the same file directory with one another.

When I select a file using the submit form (test file is 'testFilego.txt' and 3 bytes in size'), i get the following error:  `http://localhost/PhP_exercises/__tizag/280-php-fileupload-test.php?MAX_FILE_SIZE=2500000&uploadedfile=testFilego.txt`. The submit form doesn't seem to connect to the handler (?). I thought the test file would appear in my uploads folder. Help.

This is the submit form:

```
<form>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="280-php-uploader.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2500000" />
      Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
   </form>
</form>
```

This is the file hander the form ought to be contacting

```
<?php
280-php-uploader.php&lt?php

//This is '280-php-uploader.php' 
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

// Add the original filename to our target path.
//Result is "uploads/filename.extension"
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why you put a form in a form? Maybe this can be the problem, Can you try to remove the first <form>?

Comment: That seems to have been the issue. I so did not see that i had a form inside a form, hence it was posting to itself i guess. Thank you Marco for your keen eye!

Answer (score 0):

As Marco Acierno observed, i'd posted the form inside a form and that seems to have caused the problem.